# Where was this photo taken?

Tags: landscape, mountain

Got this when logging in to my PC this evening, appears to be one heck of a ski resort, just not sure where (I'm guessing France?)

[image]

Comment: Flagging as off topic, this used to be a common type of question on travel.stackoverflow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a question about the photograph; it is a question about the location.

Comment: Why guess France? Pretty random guess

Comment: @osullic I've been to the mid-west, those mountains don't resemble the Rockies, beyond that just a randmon guess (it ain't NY, that's for sure :-) )

Comment: Also relevant: https://superuser.com/q/1011968/395057

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the [Dachstein Mountains in Austria](http://www.derdachstein.at/en), showing the south face of Hunerkogel. Indeed, it is one heck of a sky resort and offers many other activities such as glacier trekking and paragliding.

Answer (score 2):

To locate photos and their owner, maybe find a bigger size or buy it, try TinEye or Google Images.

[TinEye the photo](https://tineye.com/search/3a76a9edddd555e199d12ee1f92ebc26f401caf5/).

[Buy royalty free rights from Getty Images](http://httphttp://www.gettyimages.ca/detail/photo/austria-schladming-dachstein-mountains-with-south-royalty-free-image/557388525).

TinEye sorts for: Best Match, Most Changed, Biggest Image, Newest and Oldest.

[Google Images](https://www.google.ca/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZiug03hQpW-CHzCy_1R2oi-WTbFxOkQM476Td0erUb7uSBTDUQpMGybde1DXdjXelvblx6uVDmz3kQGXVMKvHtUmmiHYlBBwqW4tIm8zcqWVYVFFLYYi8xVgc39hHJEzob02NVWH-or9eD2BRGf85ibEbcR1ou3-5P2TmnnXJjnVpXr5OTmDGSsxD3muHIH34acqrUj080hGD-BzjQSucKifOtCy_1C7XpKTnSLOmB6V5bIciR11dlwQT3xoO_1-jcaMiiYxbi_1IShLQey7gFFajoBw-ZI7QK6uk2Nt0AoSpQH7KIkGRNdvN8NJHEAW-73JeZ9KEESfQsWTsahxliHpFXKn5wTWMw&hl=en-CA) returns a "Best Match" Link which can be refined by Size, Time, and Rights along with a regular Google Search returning "About 25,270,000,000 results, in total, but only seven Links" (in this case) including [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoher_Dachstein) (and a different photo), the 'Tourist Site' for the mountain, and a few other sites willing to sell the image.

Comment: yes, thank you, much better resources for identifying photos

Comment: You're welcome, but you should ensure that the wording of your question doesn't lead to a misunderstanding which results in it's deletion.